# Excel macro to add up (sum) the value of two cells based on the common value of another cell

Tags: excel

I have a Excel sheet with data like this:

```
DNIS _ _ _ _ _   Numbers

442890512221,     10

442890512221,     4

442890512222,     7

442890512222,     5

442890512223,     2

442890512224,     14

442890512224,     13
```

I'm looking for a Macro that can add up the two number values (2nd column) if the value in the first column is equal and place that total in the third column and then to delete the second row.

The issue is that there not always are 2 rows and by deleting a second row the pointer for a loop keeps changing.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
DNIS _ _ _ _ ,   Numbers

442890512221,     14

442890512222,     12

442890512223,     2

442890512224,     27
```

Is there a smart way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: Use a **Pivot Table**.

Comment: If pivot table doesn't suit, you could use `SUMIF` function for third column, then cope/pasteSpecial->Paste values for third column and then select all columns and remove duplicates in first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Pivote table** using your data.

Only you need select on the menu the option Insert - Pivote Table and select the data. After you selection of data in the assistant select first column as Row Field and the second as Data Item.

Comment: Thanks I never thought about using a PIV table to get the results.